# Gas furnance runs blower and signals false flame

Tags: furnace

My 7yo-ish furnace is running blower excessively.  It reports (according to manual) a "false flame sensed" (5-blinks).

This is NOT, however, in response to the start of a heating cycle.  To be sure, I've disconnected the thermostat wire at the furnace. It just spontaneously starts and runs for about 10-15mins before stopping and starting up soon after.  It seemingly runs the heating cycle just fine (at least it **starts** on request), its just running the blower at other times.  I should add that the blower and vent motor start simultaneously, as opposed delayed sequence during a normal heating cycle.

I've cleaned the oxide layer on the flame sensor (and measured improvement, from 1uA to ~5uA), and for a while it seemed to resolve the issue, but not for long.   I've now disconnected the flame sensor and the blower still starts and stops.

The board appears dust and debris-free and the wiring looks in good condition, so I don't think it's intermittent short.

I'm prepared to declare it a faulty board, but is there any other sensor or any specific wiring to check first?  The hot surface igniter needs replacing (relative high resistance) but it ignite gas just fine; can it cause a "false flame sensed"?

Furnace is Goodman GMNT040-3B

Comment: What make/model is the furnace?

Comment: I take it these spurious cycles are not accompanied by any flame or smell of gas?

Comment: No gas or flames.    I have turned off the gas for the time being but as far as i can tell, the gas valve nor the ignitor is energized.